# which is the Easy and Simple way to Read json into php?

Tags: php, json

I am new to json. I wanted to read data from JSON file into the php file.

My json file data is like this

```
{"multicast_id":8925377088262649527,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}
```

I just want to check the `success` and `failure` value. I used

```
json_decode($jason_string,true);
```

But it is not working on my server. I don't know the reason.

So please tell me the easiest way to solve this problem and please explain in detail.

Comment: Why json_decode is not working on your server? What error you do you get?

Comment: Do you get any errors when you use json_decode? What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: it give me this error 'Fatal error: Call to undefined function: json_decode() in C:\inetpub\vhosts\hariomcards.com\httpdocs\QRme\Testing.php on line 14'

Comment: _json\_decode_ is not available under php versions prior to 5.2.0

Answer (score 1):

You code should work.

```
<?php 
$somestring = <<<HEREDOC
{"multicast_id":8925377088262649527,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results"$
HEREDOC;

var_dump(json_decode($somestring, true));
```

Output as expected:

```
chris@chris-UX31E:~$ php test.php 
array(5) {
  ["multicast_id"]=>
  int(8925377088262649527)
  ["success"]=>
  int(0)
  ["failure"]=>
  int(1)
  ["canonical_ids"]=>
  int(0)
  ["results"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["error"]=>
      string(13) "NotRegistered"
    }
  }
}
```

Please enable PHP logging for debugging purposes!
Take a look at: http://davidwinter.me/articles/2009/07/14/enable-php-error-logging/

If it's a local dev-server I prefer to display errors and enable all error-messages
http://www.dzone.com/snippets/let-php-show-all-errors

Answer (score 1):

do this :

go to -> start -> run -> cmd.exe

run:

```
c:\path\to\your\php.exe --version
```

check if you have php 5.2 or higher. (json it's bundled with php by default from 5.2) if you don't .. you need to install (http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php) or upgrade php to newer version.

u might also try to do this in shell

```
c:\path\to\your\php.exe --ini
```

edit the php.ini that shows in front of

```
Loaded Configuration File:
```

find the line

;extension=php_json.dll

remove the ';' and save, if you don't have the line you can add it. restart your web server and try again